# Sorting of array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a two array like this.

```
 $array5 = json_decode('[{"time":"12:08 PM","md5":1201},{"time":"01:00 PM","md5":1121},{"day":"03:03 PM","md5":1401},{"time":"03:36 PM","md5":1334}] 
',true);
 $array6 = json_decode('[{"time":"12:08 PM","ips":20},{"time":"01:00 PM","ips":10},{"time":"03:02 PM","ips":12},{"time":"03:36 PM","ips":11}]', true);
```

combined array using array_merge_recursive is:

```
[{"time":"12:08 PM","url":1201,"ips":20},{"time":"01:00 PM","url":1121,"ips":10},{"time":"03:03 PM","url":1401},{"time":"03:36 PM","url":1334,"ips":11},{"time":"03:02 PM","ips":12}]
```

Now i want to sort this array according to time.Is there any possible to way to sort this array according to time?

Comment: How did you retrieve the array in laravel can you explain ?

Comment: The posted text is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), not PHP code. Consequently, you don't have an array. Use [`json_decode()`](http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to create an array from it then  use [`usort()`](http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort it as you please.

Comment: yes sure i will update my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use Laravel array_sort helper method
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-sort

To avoid errors during comparison, use dates as Carbon opjects
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
$array = array_values(array_sort($array, function ($value) {
    return new Carbon($value['time']);
}));
```

Comment: To manage order we may use - $value["time"]
Also, it's possible to convert time to Carbon instance to avoid errors during comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You can use `usort` function of PHP

```
<?php
$arr_json = '[{"time":"12:08 PM","url":1201,"ips":20},{"time":"01:00 PM","url":1121,"ips":10},{"time":"03:03 PM","url":1401},{"time":"03:36 PM","url":1334,"ips":11},{"time":"03:02 PM","ips":12}]';
$arr = json_decode($arr_json,true);

function sort_by_time($a,$b)
{
  $a_time = strtotime($a['time']);
  $b_time = strtotime($b['time']);
  return $a_time > $b_time;
}
usort($arr, "sort_by_time");
print_r($arr);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/4pghd)